# QUICK BOOK WEBCONNECTOR INTEGRATION WITH PHP

Tags: php, quickbooks

iam new to Quickbook. I installed and while iam trying to integrate with my local php web application its showing error in password for the username. The webserver is wamp 2.0.
I changed the password and user name in example_we_connector and use the same in webconnector
LOG

I dont knw which username and password to use for first time in QB webconnector
Version:
PHP QuickBooks SOAP Server v3.0 at /Livehrm.new/quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.
php
Message:
Invalid password for username: admin

Description:
QBWC1040: Web connector did not provide a valid password for the given username. Job ending.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using this open-source QuickBooks library:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

The error message pretty much tells you exactly what is wrong:

> Web connector did not provide a valid password for the given username.

If you look in the `quickbooks_user` SQL table, you will see a record for the username/password to authenticate against.

Make sure the username/password in the `quickbooks_user` SQL table matches what you used in your .QWC file, and what you entered into the Web Connector.

As long as everything matches, it will work just fine.